# WPF application: create Shortcut in startup folder

Tags: wpf, setup-deployment

I created a WPF application, and I want to launch it when Windows Startup.

I created a Setup Project using visual installer project, which installs my application into Program File folder, and creates shortcut into User's Program Menu.

But how can I **create shortcut in Startup folder** ?

I have also added special folder startup folder but it doesn't work for me.
I have also set registry but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You want your WPF application automatically when windows loads, right ?

Answer (score 1):

The description here looks right to me:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8f017579-5234-4d0b-90bb-9062fa69240f/setup-project-shortcut-to-startup-folder?forum=winformssetup

In the setup project, right click on it in solution explorer then go to view > File System

next, you will see a Window in the middle of the screen with 2 window panes.

be sure to include the output project in the "Application Folder" of this treeview (click on it to select it then in the right hand window pane, right click > Add > project output > then select Primary output"

In the left hand pane "File system on target machine", right click on it then go to "Add special folder" > "User's Startup folder"

this should now create the "User startup folder" in the tree.

next, click on this folder created, then in the right hand pane, right click on it and go to Add > Create new shortcut

a dialog Window will appear so in this, select the Application folder then "Primary output from......" option
build it, and run it.

Answer (score 0):

The above given procedure is actually a right way to keep the shortcut on window startup, as the above solution is not working, you can manually also add the installed shortcut of your application in the **shell:startup** folder.